# Keras Model does not predict expected output

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am building Keras model to detect ddos attack. I have trained the model to have loss and accuracy rate as below with data set with

```
x_train = [bunch of float values]
# Like below
[6.99757033e-01 5.10532289e-06 7.74600714e-06 ... 2.93996180e-05
  6.57591467e-01 2.34854095e-02]
 [4.99968509e-01 7.93600808e-03 7.93600808e-03 ... 4.99968509e-01
  0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
 [8.72862575e-01 3.66688893e-06 1.10006668e-05 ... 1.10006668e-05
  2.45681559e-04 2.45681559e-04]
 ...
 [4.99036039e-01 1.37855260e-03 1.37855260e-03 ... 4.99036039e-01
  0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]

y_train = [0 or 1] 1 for ddos, 0 for benign
# Like below:
[[1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 ...
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]]
[[1]]
```

When epoch finishes, it gives

```
2000000/2000000 [==============================] - 22s 11us/step - loss: 0.1930 - accuracy: 0.9381
```

However, when the model predicts the input data, it should give the number close to 1, but actaully it gives value that is almost 0. I am not sure how does it predicts wrong values although it has fairly high accuracy.

My whole code is like below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing

from keras.models import Sequential

model = Sequential()

from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from keras.optimizers import Adam

model.add(Dense(units=64, activation='relu', input_dim=10))  # Input Layer
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(units=32, activation='relu'))   # hidden Layer
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(units=32, activation='relu'))   # hidden Layer
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))     # Last Layer for output

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

CSV_FILE = "ddos.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(CSV_FILE)
df.loc[(df.Label == "ddos"), "Label"] = 1.
df.loc[(df.Label == "Benign"), "Label"] = 0.
#df=df.dropna(axis="columns", how="any")

# Data set

x_train = np.array(df[["Flow Duration", "Tot Fwd Pkts", "Tot Bwd Pkts", "TotLen Fwd Pkts",
                       "Flow IAT Mean","Flow IAT Std" ,"Flow IAT Max", "Flow IAT Min",
                       "Fwd IAT Tot", "Fwd IAT Mean"]])

x_train = x_train.astype(float)

normalized_x = preprocessing.normalize(x_train)


y_train = np.array(df[["Label"]])
y_train = np.array(y_train, dtype = 'float32')

normalized_y = preprocessing.normalize(y_train)



model.fit(normalized_x, normalized_y, epochs=2, batch_size=128)




x_test = np.array([["3974862.0", "29.0","44.0","86.0" ,"55206.42", "1.954783e+05","1566821.0", "167.0",
                    "3735347", "133405.25"]])  # ddos data

x_test = preprocessing.normalize(x_test)

classes = model.predict(x_test)
threshold_output = np.where(classes > 0.5, 1, 0)
print(threshold_output)
```

Comment: Most probably, you have a highly imbalanced dataset (< 10% of ddos labels). This is a huge sub-topic in itself called *class imbalance*; I suggest you start googling ruthlessly.

Answer (score 1):

Is your dataset imbalanced? Maybe ddos labels in your dataset are rarely appeared and model didn't learn it. I think you should use other metric ( eg. F1 score ) for evaluation and try other machine learning model like Random Forest, XGboost.

Comment: Oh, I see. You don't need to normalize your label.

Comment: I already performed normalization for the data sets. Also, I am sure that every label column have a value in the set.

Comment: You mean you didn't normalize your label for now? this line `normalized_y = preprocessing.normalize(y_train)`.

Answer (score -1):

You can try one-hot-encoding the output labels into (0,1) and (1,0) instead of 0 and 1.

Comment: I am afraid that merely changing the representation of the output is not helpful here, but if you think otherwise, you are always welcome to either *demonstrate* it or point to supporting evidence *in the answer* (and not by mere linking in the comments). I do have offered a speculative answer in the comments, which is arguably the place for such purely speculative one-liners. And if you think that downvoting pre-supposes coming up with alternative answers, I kindly suggest you re-read the community rules and guidelines, because this is certainly not the case.

Comment: Please notice that 1) SO is [not a helpdesk](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254770/what-is-stack-overflow-s-goal/255019#255019) 2) lacking the reputation necessary to comment does not justify using the answer space for that purpose.